# How do you calculate the median for a variable in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, median

I am preparing a report in iReport, and I need to calculate the median of a field for a variable that will be used in a crosstab.  I noticed there is no built in calculation type for median (just highest and lowest).

[image: image of default calculations]

Is there any way to get the median or 50th percentile of a field in iReport?

Comment: I believe the average is the sum of all values / number of values.  I do not need the average, I need the 50th percentile (the mid-way point from the 1st, and last number) of the field.

Comment: The JasperReports Server has expression for calculating median vaue - you can try to look at source code

Comment: [Median Calculation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/956516/median-calculation) - post on Jaspersoft community

Comment: ok, i'd prefer to not dip into the sql too much more, but it looks like it might be my only option as of now. I can't see why JasperSoft wouldn't have added that as a built-in calculation.  Either way, thank you for pointing me towards a possible solution. @AlexK

Comment: You are welcome :) Do you have JR Server?

Comment: Just an idea: create ad-hoc report with Median expression and try to import this report. Maybe it can help you

Comment: BTW, The source code of JR framework (6.2) does not contain *"median"* word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no builtin median calculation in JasperReports.

A median can still be obtained by manually collecting the values in a list and then using [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) to do the computation.

See the following example.  The report also uses [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to convert a wrapper array to a primitive array.  To run the report, you will need to add commons-math3-x.y.z.jar and commons-lang3-x.y.jar to the classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FirstJasper" columnCount="1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30">
    <style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="8"/>
    <queryString>SELECT * FROM Orders</queryString>
    <field name="Freight" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <variable name="FreightList" class="java.util.List">
        <variableExpression>$V{FreightList}</variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression>new java.util.ArrayList()</initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="AddFreight" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <variableExpression>$V{FreightList}.add($F{Freight})</variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="350" height="40"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["median is " + org.apache.commons.math3.stat.StatUtils.percentile(org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.toPrimitive((Double[]) $V{FreightList}.toArray(new Double[$V{FreightList}.size()])), 50)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="13">
            <textField pattern="0.00">
                <reportElement x="5" y="0" width="350" height="11"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Freight}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: do i need to add a reference to a class or anything? I tried to add this to a text field, but im getting  
org.apache.commons.math3.stat.StatsUtils cannot be resolved to a type
org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils cannot be resolved to a type
the method toArray(Double) is undefined for type Double

@dada67

Comment: Yes, you need commons-math3 and commons-lang3 jars in your classpath.  I edited the answer to make the requirements more clear.

Comment: Good question and the great answer